# issue with form validation in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I currently have a login page which contains the PHP code below to login. The login works fine however if I put an incorrect password or even if I do not fill in the username or password fields it outputs the error `Account not confirmed. Please contact support.` I can't really see why this is either..

```
if(isset($_POST['doLogin'])){
        $username = $_POST['login-username'];
        $password = $_POST['login-password'];


        if(empty($username) || empty($password)){
            $error = error("Please enter all fields");
        }


        /// Main Checks Against the Inputs

        $SQLCheckLoginn = $odb -> prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username");
        $SQLCheckLoginn -> execute(array(':username' => $username));
        $countLoginn = $SQLCheckLoginn -> fetchColumn(0);
        if ($countLoginn < 1){
            $SQL = $odb -> prepare("INSERT INTO `loginlogs` VALUES(:username, :ip, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), 'XX')");
            $SQL -> execute(array(':username' => $username." - does not exist",':ip' => $ip));
            $error = error("The username does not exist in our system.");
        }

        $SQLCheckLogin = $odb -> prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username AND `password` = :password");
        $SQLCheckLogin -> execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => SHA1($password)));
        $countLogin = $SQLCheckLogin -> fetchColumn(0);
        if (!($countLogin == 1)){
            $SQL = $odb -> prepare("INSERT INTO `loginlogs` VALUES(:username, :ip, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), 'XX')");
            $SQL -> execute(array(':username' => $username." - failed login",':ip' => $ip));
            $error = error('The password you entered is invalid.');
        }

        $SQL = $odb -> prepare("SELECT `status` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username");
        $SQL -> execute(array(':username' => $username));
        $status = $SQL -> fetchColumn(0);
        if ($status == 1){
            $SQL = $odb -> prepare("SELECT `reason` FROM `bans` WHERE `username` = :username");
            $SQL -> execute(array(':username' => $username));
            $ban = $SQL -> fetchColumn(0);
            if(empty($ban)){ $ban = "No reason given."; }
            $error = error('You are banned. Reason: '.htmlspecialchars($ban));
        }       


        $SQL = $odb -> prepare("SELECT `email_active` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username");
        $SQL -> execute(array(':username' => $username));
        $fetch = $SQL -> fetchColumn(0);
        if ($fetch == "0"){
            $error = error('Account not confirmed. Please contact support.');       
        }

        // Check if 2auth enabled
        if(empty($error)){

            $SQL = $odb -> prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username");       $SQL -> execute(array(':username' => $username));
            $userInfo = $SQL -> fetch();
            $ipcountry = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=".$ip)) -> {'geoplugin_countryName'};
            if (empty($ipcountry)) {$ipcountry = 'XX';}
            $SQL = $odb -> prepare('INSERT INTO `loginlogs` VALUES(:username, :ip, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), :ipcountry)');
            $SQL -> execute(array(':ip' => $ip, ':username' => $username, ':ipcountry' => $ipcountry));
            $_SESSION['username'] = $userInfo['username'];
            $_SESSION['ID'] = $userInfo['ID'];
            $_SESSION['email'] = $userInfo['email'];
            setcookie("username", $userInfo['username'], time() + 720000);
            header('Location: dashboard');

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not break if you find an error, so even if the username does not exist, you still check for password etc.

Now you come to the point `if ($fetch == "0")` - where I assume `$fetch` is equivalent to `false`. Note that PHP does not have types. "0" is also interpreted as `false` and hence `if ($fetch == "0")` is true.

> When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE:
>
> the boolean FALSE itself
>
> the integer 0 (zero)
>
> the float 0.0 (zero)
>
> the empty string, **and the string "0"**
>
> an array with zero elements
>
> the special type NULL (including unset variables)
>
> SimpleXML objects created from empty tags

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

Comment: when I change `if ($fetch == "0")` to `if ($fetch == false)` I still get `Account not confirmed. Please contact support.` Do I need to `return false;` after each error? i'm not sure..

Comment: Obviously that didn't change anything. I was trying to tell you that `"0"` is the same as `false`. You could also do something like `if ($fetch == "0" && count($errors == 0))`

Comment: I tried using `die($error = error("Please enter all fields"));` which works however it now shows the message on a blank page instead of on the same page.

Comment: Yeah, die isn't a good idea, as it will stop the rest of the page from being generated. You might end up with a half-done page. Rather use returns, breaks or count the elements in your error array.

Comment: tried using `return;` and `break;` after each error message however just get a blank page.

Comment: Also i don't think break would work as according to PHP manual it mentions 'break ends execution of the current for, foreach, while, do-while or switch structure.'

Comment: You use returns in functions, breaks in loops, dies on critical error messages (e.g. database connection cannot be established). Here, rather do what I mentioned in my previous comment... `if ($fetch == "0" && count($errors == 0))` Just check for two conditions

Comment: Thank you, this definitely somewhat works more than before. I set variable `$errors = 0` and then did `$errors = $errors + 1;` after each error message as well as adding `if ($fetch == "0" && count($errors == 0))` to banned message and it worked. Only problem is now that `Please enter all fields` and `The username does not exist in our system.` don't work.

Comment: `$errors = 0` is not what you want. `$errors` is an array for you and you add messages to that entry with each error that comes up. Setting it to the integer 0 kills all messages within. Don't set it to 0 - simply use `count`. Also, `count($errors == 0))` does not make any sense at all. It evaluates to `count(true)` or `count(false)`